# Chamar uma macro em modulos diferentes

Tags: vba

Galera bom dia, criei varias macros,porem quero unificar tudo, as mesmas estao em modulos diferentes.

como faço para juntar elas e executar tudo de uma vez?

segue o cod que encontrei mas nao deu certo

```
Sub executar()
    MsgBox "Mensagem de aviso que ira iniciar"
    Call dahs01
End Sub

Sub dahs01()
    Call Module6.Dash_01
End Sub
```

Comment: Favor ler a [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas) para ver como formatar o código. E para códigos maiores você pode utilizar [este site](http://rubberduckvba.com/indentation) para realizar a identação.

Comment: Feito! Obrigado pela dica de identação

Comment: Como estão declaradas? São Public ou Private? Se forem Públicas, basta chamar o nome da função ou Sub no Sub executar, escrevendo o nome do Sub, sem a necessidade de especificar o módulo. E não há a necessidade de usar o `Call`. E elas estão na mesma pasta de trabalho?

Comment: Estão como Sub, são public

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Exemplo

Um exemplo simples será demonstrado, com a seguinte árvore no VBA:

[image: Árvore de Projeto VBA]

Então, assume que toda a programação está na mesma Pasta de Trabalho.

No módulo1 haverá o `Sub executar()`

No módulo2 o seguinte código:

```
Sub teste1()
    MsgBox "1"
End Sub
```

E no módulo 3:

```
Sub teste2(text As String)
    MsgBox text
End Sub

Private Sub teste3()
    MsgBox "3"
End Sub
```

### Explicação

Ao executar com o seguinte código:

```
Sub executar()
    Call teste1                                  'Não é necessário o Call, somente o VBA ainda utiliza esta sintaxe

    teste2 "2"

    teste3
End Sub
```

Ocorrerá um erro em `teste3`, pois ele é uma `Private Sub` do módulo3.

Porém ao executar com:

```
Sub executar()
    Call teste1                                  'Não é necessário o Call, somente o VBA ainda utiliza esta sintaxe

    teste2 "2"
End Sub
```

O código funcionará corretamente, pois mesmo que teste1() e teste2() estejam em outros módulos, eles são declarados como Public.

Para rodar uma Private Sub de outro módulo, utilize:

```
Sub executar()
    teste1

    teste2 ("2")

    Application.Run "Módulo3.teste3"
End Sub
```

Portanto, é necessário chamar os Subs em um outro Sub para realizar isto.

> Para um código mais avançado, refira a esta referência: [Programming The VBA Editor](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx). Em que você pode realizar ações dentro do Projeto VBA, podendo listar os Subs dos módulos e dar run.

Comment: Excelente! obrigado pela ajuda